# Content security policy not appearing in response headers

Tags: express, content-security-policy

I have an express server running with the following setup, but the Content Security Policy response headers do not appear in Chrome Dev Tools - any ideas?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader(
        'Content-Security-Policy',
        "default-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; frame-src 'self'; upgrade-insecure-requests;"
    );
    next();
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'server/static/index.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is not setHeader, just header

```js
export function headers (req, res, next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS,HEAD,GET,PUT,POST,PATCH");
    res.header("Accept-Language", "es, en");
    res.header(
        "Content-Security-Policy",
        "default-src 'self'; base-uri: 'self'; strict-dynamic 'self'; manifest-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'"
    );
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, Csrf-Token, Accept-Language, Content-Type, Accept, Range"
    );

    next();
}
....
express.use(headers);
```

There is one package call helmet which is a must for any express app

Comment: I tried helmet, but couldn't get the content security policy to work either.

Comment: using `res.header` didn't work either. Clearly something with my setup. This running on http://localhost:3001 - does that make any difference?